# Unable to run Appium Version 1.3.6-(Ophiuchus) on Yosemite for Testing Android App on real device

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, appium

These are my settings:

- My **SDK path**: `-/usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk`
- My **APK path** `-/usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/Setmore.apk`
- Given **Package name, Launch Activity,Platform Name, Automation Name, Platform Version and Device name**.
- In General Settings, I have enabled **Check for Updates** and **Prelauch appln**.

But when I run *appium* with the following command:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk"; '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --pre-launch --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "4.4" --app "/usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/Setmore.apk" --app-pkg "com.adaptavant.setmore" --app-activity ".ui.SetmoreLoginActivity" --device-name "Google Nexus 4"
```

I am getting this error:

> /Users/sathiya/.bash_profile: line 3:
> /usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools: is a
> directory
>
> /Users/sathiya/.bash_profile: line 5:
> /usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools: is a
> directory /Users/sathiya/.bash_profile: line 8:
> /Users/sathiya/.p/usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/apirofile:
> No such file or directory
>
> info: [debug] Starting Appium in pre-launch mode
>
> info: Pre-launching app
>
> info: [debug] Using local app from command line:
> /usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/Setmore.apk
>
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session
> a10600c8-ec32-489d-8700-e772c0038efa info: Starting android appium
>
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
>
> info: Java version is: 1.8.0_40
>
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>
> error: uncaughtException: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>
> '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools'
> date=Sat Mar 07 2015 12:23:41 GMT+0530 (IST), pid=8102, uid=502,
> gid=20,
> cwd=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium,
> execPath=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node,
> version=v0.12.0,
> argv=[/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node,
> /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/main.js,
> --pre-launch, --automation-name, Appium, --platform-name, Android, --platform-version, 4.4, --app, /usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/Setmore.apk,
> --app-pkg, com.adaptavant.setmore, --app-activity, .ui.SetmoreLoginActivity, --device-name, Google Nexus 4],
> rss=82657280, heapTotal=66926080, heapUsed=44453472,
> loadavg=[2.06689453125, 2.0908203125, 2.08740234375], uptime=73702,
> trace=[column=null, file=null, function=Error, line=null, method=null,
> native=true, column=18, file=fs.js, function=Object.fs.readdirSync,
> line=765, method=fs.readdirSync, native=false, column=18,
> file=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/helpers.js,
> function=exports.getDirectories, line=100, method=getDirectories,
> native=false, column=25,
> file=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js,
> function=ADB.checkSdkBinaryPresent, line=97,
> method=checkSdkBinaryPresent, native=false, column=8,
> file=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js,
> function=ADB.checkAdbPresent, line=134, method=checkAdbPresent,
> native=false, column=7,
> file=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js,
> function=Function.ADB.createADB, line=73, method=ADB.createADB,
> native=false, column=9,
> file=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js,
> function=androidCommon.initAdb, line=1059, method=initAdb,
> native=false, column=21,
> file=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js,
> function=null, line=610, method=null, native=false, column=17,
> file=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js,
> function=null, line=249, method=null, native=false, column=13,
> file=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js,
> function=iterate, line=149, method=null, native=false], stack=[Error:
> ENOENT, no such file or directory
> '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools',
> at Error (native),     at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:765:18),     at
> exports.getDirectories
> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/helpers.js:100:18),
> at ADB.checkSdkBinaryPresent
> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js:97:25),
> at ADB.checkAdbPresent
> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js:134:8),
> at Function.ADB.createADB
> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js:73:7),
> at androidCommon.initAdb
> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/android/android-common.js:1059:9),
> at
> /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:610:21,
> at
> /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:249:17,
> at iterate
> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:149:13)]

Comment: I think your appium software not downloaded properly..Or corrupted.OR there is lot of thing missing in your code.

Comment: When i run appium doctor:Running iOS Checks
✔ Xcode is installed at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed.
✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
✔ Node binary found at /usr/local/bin/node
✔ iOS Checks were successful.

Running Android Checks
✖ ANDROID_HOME is set but does not exist on the file system at "$/usr/local/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk"

Comment: Ohh. you are having Ios Os. I think you will get exact and fast solution here : discuss.appium.io

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed SDK Studio, If you did, then try these configurations.
They worked for me.
`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/ivcmbp020adm/Library/Android/sdk`
`export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`